# open activity based on item selected in spinner

Tags: android, android-activity, spinner

I need to start activity(ies) based on the selected item from the spinner.

There are two spinner, One contains the Year and another one contains Course name. The second spinner needs to be set dynamically based on the selection in the first spinner ( selecting the year, some courses are of 3 year and some of 4 years, so 3 year course shouldn't be shown when 4th year is selected in spinner one).

After the selection of both the spinner, i want to start activity based on both the values he choose so that he download the required syllabus.

Comment: What did you tried? What went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Hopefully it will help or at least give some idea:

```
            List<String> spinnerArrayYear = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> spinnerArraySubject = new ArrayList<String>();

            spinnerArray.add("2013");
            spinnerArray.add("2014");
            spinnerArray.add("2015");
            spinnerArray.add("2016");

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArrayYear);

            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            Spinner sItems = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.year_spinner);
            sItems.setAdapter(adapter);

            sItems.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                    Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
                    String text = item.toString();

                    if(text.equals("2013")) {
                        spinnerArraySubject.add("Chemistry");
                        spinnerArraySubject.add("Math");
                    } else if (text.equals("2014")) {
                        spinnerArraySubject.add("Chemistry");
                        spinnerArraySubject.add("Math");
                        spinnerArraySubject.add("History"); 
                    } else if (text.equals("2015")) {
                        spinnerArraySubject.add("French");
                    } else if (text.equals("2016")) {
                        spinnerArraySubject.add("French");
                        spinnerArraySubject.add("Math");
                    }
                }
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                }
            });

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArraySubject);
    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        Spinner sItems2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.subject_spinner);
        sItems2.setAdapter(adapter2);

        sItems2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
                String text = item.toString();

                //DO SOMETHING
            }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
```